# Given $\frac{f(2^n)}{f(2^{n+1})} = 11/18 + n/18$, how do you find $f(x)$ in terms of $x$?

Tags: functions, recursion

If I have a semi-recursive equation for a function $f$, namely,

$f(2^n)/f(2^{n+1}) = 11/18 + n/18$ for all real values of n,

How do I convert this (without a programmable computer) to a non-recursive formula for $f(x)$ in terms of $x$?

Assume a value of $f(1) = H$ for some constant $H$.

Edit: It would be best to get a closed formula for $f(x)$ that does not include factorials, because I will eventually differentiate a function that includes this one. Also, factorials do not allow me to include negative numbers or nonintegers in the domain.

Comment: Hint: can you find closed formula for $a_{n+1}=\frac{18}{n+11}a_{n}$ in term of factorial ?

Comment: @zwim Good point, but my next step is to find the maximum of a function that involves this, which means I will have to differentiate a factorial. It would be better to have a closed formula for f(x) without factorials. In fact, I will edit that info into the question.

Comment: The factorial get dominant quite quickly (so it is decreasing after $n\ge 9$), also the curve seems quite flat around maximum $a_7=a_8$ so having the exact abscissa is maybe not important, just use $a_7$ as maximum if an approximation is sufficient.

Comment: @zwim Seeing the maximum of the curve itself is insufficient, because I needed to find the maximum of a more complicated function that includes this one, but luckily desmos was strong enough to let me find what I needed. An approximation was sufficient. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=f(2^x)$. So $$\frac{g(n)}{g(n+1)}=\frac{11+n}{18}$$ In other words, $$g(n+1)=\frac{18}{11+n}g(n)$$
Let $g(x)=18^xk(x)$. So
$$k(n+1)=\frac{1}{11+n}k(n)$$
Let $k(x)=\frac{1}{(10+x)!}m(x)$, so
$$m(n+1)=m(n)$$

Let $m(n)$ be constant: $m(n)=m$.

So $k(n)=\frac{m}{(10+n)!}$.

So $g(n)=\frac{18^nm}{(10+n)!}$.

So $f(n)=\frac{18^{\log_2(n)}m}{(10+\log_2(n))!}$. aThe factorial applied to general real numbers should be interpreted as the Gamma function, shifted by $1$: $$f(n)=\frac{18^{\log_2(n)}m}{\Gamma(11+\log_2(n))}$$
For $f(1)=H$, you need $m=H\cdot\Gamma(11)$.